# Set selected View highlighted - random changing of the View while scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, view, onitemclicklistener, setbackground

**What I tried**

---

Hello Guys, I have made a GridView which I've filled over my database. Now I made an onItemClickListner, from the Google GridView tutorial. Now I tried to make that when the user clicks on a picture in the GridView, it keeps selected and gets a backgroundcolor so the user sees which Image he chooses.
But exactly this isn't working how it should. I made a If with a boolean which allways when the User clicks on the next View, that the old View gets transperent again and the new clicked View got a backgroundcolor. But after I selected a View and I scroll up and down. The highlighted View changes sometimes randomstyled.

**Question**

---

So my question is what I have to change in my onItemClickListner, that this random View changing stops (?), I didn't found out a way to do so. And is there a easier way to highlight the selected View?
For the understanding "selected View" = User clicks on it, than its selected and should be highlighted.

**Code**

---

Here's the Code of my onItemClickListner:

```
    //Hier wird die Grindview gefüllt
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.SmileyGrind);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, info));


    //Hier wird gemerkt welches bild
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

boolean color = false;
View vv;


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(SFilterConfigActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // gridview.setSelection(position);

            if ( color == false){
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                vv = v;
                color = true;

            }
            else {
                vv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                vv = v;


            }


        }      
    });
```

---

Thx for you help in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue but it was with ListView .follow this it will work for GridView too.

```
if(position == grid.getSelectedItemPosition())
   holder._linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);           
else  
   holder._linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and get the Parent Layout of the Layout that you are using for your GridView and on onClick method of layout just add this .

```
 holder._linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

This will change the Background color of the layout and the above code will solve your random background problem.

Comment: Hello Thx for you fast answer so I changed to Code to this `             if(position == gridview.getSelectedItemPosition()){
              gridview.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
              
             }
             else{
              gridview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
             }`But it dosn't work, what am I still doing wrong? Thx for your help (+1)!

Comment: This code you should write in the getView() method of the ImageAdapter and did you implement change background color on OnClick of the GridView .

Comment: I really don't get how to implement that. Could you give me please a quick look at your ImageAdapter and the ListView File. I really like to do this by my own..

Comment: or a least how should that `holder._linear.`part look in my code, I don't get it.

Comment: you have to create Custom Layout XML for your GridView and pass it to your Adapter as we do for custom ListView. Then you have to get the Parent Layout in the XML and change its background .